# Why can't I get my NIVIDA drivers to work

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I've tried everything:
messing around in my xorg.conf file,
purging my nvidia driver and reinstalling,
updating my headers
unplugging and plugging everything back in,
(turning on and off again)
enabling drivers manually,
installing and uninstalling ubuntu-desktop and NVIDIA common,
updating,
upgrading,
manual installs via .run,
starting lightdm and startx.

I figured our it was something to do with my video card setting to high of a resolution. After resetting that I at least got to the tty terminal. But nothing I did would bring up the GUI. Nothing. I'm using a Nvidia 560 gtx on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

If there's a single person who can help me I will give you a hug, put pizza in my hard drive, and E-mail it to you!

**UPDATE**
Used sgfxi (good idea), now the only problem is that I can't get to my desktop. Startx says it can't find a screen and after looking through the log it says failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0. I have a desktop and all of the search results talk about bumblebee, which if I'm not mistaken is for laptops with optimus.
There's a lot of info and I can make ends of it, but I don't know what to look for. Any help (I can't paste from terminal because I have no idea how).

Comment: When you use the "Try Ubuntu" option, edit your question and add this information: from the terminal the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A6 VGA`, `lsmod`. Also, please detail the solutions you have tried and what changed between each. You say that the GUI don't start? Is there an error message? Can you upload the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file to http://paste.ubuntu.com? Remember to **edit your question** and add the required information, **do not use comments**.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script  [smxi script](http://smxi.org/)
It will automatically detect your hardware configuration and install nvidia driver.
Also there are bunch of other stuffs.

I past I had used this script on my debian wheezy.
Here's what I had used [How To : Smxi script](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=22740)

Hope this helps n hope I get that ePizza